# Unable to install some programs in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I've recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS.
While trying to install some programs (in particular, Okular and Amarok) from the console, I get variations of the following error (my Ubuntu is in Spanish, so I'll post the English version of the error that I found online):

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
okular : Depends: libokularcore7 (= 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) but but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: kde-runtime (> 4:4.10) but but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libkio5 (>= 4:4.14) but but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libkparts4 (>= 4:4.14) but but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libkprintutils4 (>= 4:4.14) but but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried fixing broken packages with Synaptic, apart from several commands that according to the internet (in particular [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)) might help, but none did:

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

...etc

This is the result of running     cat /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse main universe restricted
```

Anyone got any ideas?

UPDATE: I'm adding the result of running     cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* , in case it's of any use.

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/ /
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/ /
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/audacity-team/daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/audacity-team/daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/audacity-team/daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/audacity-team/daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/audacity-team/daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/audacity-team/daily/ubuntu trusty main
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily main
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu trusty main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
# deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
# deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
# deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
# deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /
# deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /
# deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./
# deb http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./
# deb http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free
# This file makes sure that Opera Browser is kept up-to-date
# as part of regular system upgrades

# deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
# This file makes sure that Opera Browser is kept up-to-date
# as part of regular system upgrades

# deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
# This file makes sure that Opera Browser is kept up-to-date
# as part of regular system upgrades

# deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ trusty main
# deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ trusty main
# deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/darktable-release/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/darktable-release/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/darktable-release/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/darktable-release/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/darktable-release/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/darktable-release/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
# deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
# deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/utappia/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/utappia/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/utappia/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/utappia/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/utappia/stable/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/utappia/stable/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial main
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment out these lines from file /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

(3-rd and 4-th from the bottom)

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install okular
```

**EDIT**

After reviewing what is in your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* I would suggest to get rid of:

```
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily main
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free
```

(basically anything non-xenial)

Then again try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install okular`.

Comment: Doesn't work. =( I get the same "unmet dependencies" and "you have held broken packages" error as before. I added results of running     cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* , just in case.

Comment: "Get rid of" implies commenting out those lines, right? I did that and once again it didn't work... Tough one, ah? Thanks for your help!